# Как преобразовать строку в double на C#?

Tags: c#, строки

Как преобразовать следующую строку в формат `double`: `8.000000e-02`

Пробую так:

```
Double res1 = Double.Parse("8.000000e-02");
```

Говорит входная строка имеет неверный формат!
Кстати: `Convert.ToDouble()` тоже не работает!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так :

```
var res = double.Parse("8.000000e-02", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но я сделал так:  Double res1 = Convert.ToDouble(result, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));